# Convert .pb file (Tensorflow model file) to human readable format

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, protocol-buffers

I am new to tensorflow. I have downloaded and run the image classifier provided on tensorflow website. I can see [link](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz) that downloads model from web. 
I have to read the .pb file in human readable format.

Is this possible? if yes, How?
Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If you mean the model architecture then I recommend looking at the graph in Tensorboard, the graph visualisation tool provided with Tensorflow. I'm pretty sure that the demo code/tutorial already implements all the code required to import into tensorboard so it should just be a case or running tensorboard and pointing it to the log directory. (This should be defined in the code near the top).

Then run `tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/logs/` and click the graphs tab. You will then see the various graphs for the different runs.

Alternatively, there are a couple of papers on inception that describe the model and the theory behind it. One is available [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567.pdf)

Hope that helps you understand inception a bit more.

Comment: The OP want human readable file from that protobuf file, not the concept of Inception model.